# can't get Groovy ConfigSlurper to parse a String and find result as property

Tags: parsing, groovy, configuration-files

I'm having a really simple problem getting `ConfigSlurper` to process my config

Groovy version 2.5.6

Went back to basics and tried this simple Groovy script:

```
ConfigSlurper slurper = new ConfigSlurper ()    
slurper.parse ("""host='localhost' """)

println slurper.getProperty('host')

/* gives exception :
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: host for class: groovy.util.ConfigSlurper
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: host for class: groovy.util.ConfigSlurper
    at scripts.testSSlurper.run(testSSlurper.groovy:7)
 */
```

Why doesn't this simple parse fail?

What am I doing wrong here?  This is a blocker for the real code I've written parsing a file - which also seems to bind nothing into slurper.

Answer (score 4):

There is one misunderstanding in your code sample. Parsing a config script does not mutate the `ConfigSlurper` object, but it returns a `ConfigObject` instead. All you have to do is to capture the result of `slurper.parse(script)` method and access `host` key from the returned `ConfigObject` instance.

```
ConfigSlurper slurper = new ConfigSlurper()

def config = slurper.parse(""" host = 'localhost' """)

println config.getProperty("host")
```

The output:

```
localhost
```

Comment: How do I deal with variables...meaning if i have { host = "localhost" } in a variable say "str" ?! and localhost is within "double quotes".. And how do we access nested elements like { users { username = "User" } }

Comment: Answering my own comment:

1st Replace "" with ' ' using .replaceAll( "\"", "\'" )

and then access like config.porperty.subProperty.subProperty ...